# msnodesql module is getting error during compilation

Tags: sql-server, node.js, azure, express, azure-sql-database

```
 C:\Python27>node-gyp configure
 gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
 gyp info using node-gyp@0.11.0
 gyp info using node@0.10.21 | win32 | ia32
 gyp info spawn python
 gyp info spawn args [ 'C:\\Users\\v-javde\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\
 node-gyp\\gyp\\gyp',
 gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
 gyp info spawn args   '-f',
 gyp info spawn args   'msvs',
 gyp info spawn args   '-G',
 gyp info spawn args   'msvs_version=auto',
 gyp info spawn args   '-I',
 gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Python27\\build\\config.gypi',
 gyp info spawn args   '-I',
 gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\v-javde\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\
 node-gyp\\addon.gypi',
 gyp info spawn args   '-I',
 gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\v-javde\\.node-gyp\\0.10.21\\common.gypi',
 gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
 gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
 gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\\Users\\v-javde\\.node-gyp\\0.10.21',
 gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=C:\\Python27',
 gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
 gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
 gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Python27\\build',
 gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.' ]
 gyp: binding.gyp not found (cwd: C:\Python27) while trying to load binding.gyp
 gyp ERR! configure error
 gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
 gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (C:\Users\v-javde\AppData\Roaming\np
 m\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:467:16)
 gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
 gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:789:
 12)
 gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
 gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Users\\v-javde\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules
 \\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure"
 gyp ERR! cwd C:\Python27
 gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.21
 gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.11.0
 gyp ERR! not ok
```

I have only two major requirements. 1. Azure SQL 2. NodeIIS, I have seen some tutorial online that works but when I tried it failed. I was thinking it might be due to the latest node.js version... i'm currently running v0.10.21, I have tried both 32 and 64 without success.

Is there anyone that has success of using this, what version of node.js you use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're running `node-gyp configure` in the wrong directory.

Find the root directory of the Node.js module, and execute the command there instead. You will know you're in the correct directory when there is a file named `binding.gyp`, because that is the file node-gyp is looking for.

Here's the bit from your own error that explains it:

```
gyp: binding.gyp not found (cwd: C:\Python27) while trying to load binding.gyp
```